# MediaElement volume - speed

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp

I am building a UWP app with a `MediaElement`.
I would like to be able to change the volume and the play speed of the `MediaElement`, but my code doesn’t work properly.
If I set the volume and speed before playing the first time it works, but if I change eg. Volume after playback it doesn’t change the volume.

My code:

```vb
Private mElement As MediaElement

Private Async Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    mElement = New MediaElement
    AddHandler mElement.MediaEnded, AddressOf OnMediaEnded
End Sub

Async Function SayAsync(ByVal text As String) As Task
    If Synth Is Nothing Then
        Dim chosenVoice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(Function(v) v.DisplayName.Contains(cboVoice.SelectedItem.ToString))
        Synth = New SpeechSynthesizer() With {.Voice = chosenVoice}
    End If
    currentStream = Await Synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text)
    mElement.Volume = SpeechVol / 100
    mElement.PlaybackRate = SpeechSpeed / 100
    mElement.SetSource(currentStream, String.Empty)
    mElement.Play()
End Function

Private Sub OnMediaEnded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    currentStream?.Dispose()
    currentStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By testing on my side, the [`Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.volume#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaElement_Volume) could be correctly changed when the audio is playing. Since your code snippet are only parts of the whole, the following is a completed demo that can work well on my side:

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="rootgrid"> 
   <Button x:Name="btnstart" Click="btnstart_Click" Content="start play"></Button>
   <Button x:Name="btnchangevolume" Click="btnchangevolume_Click" Content="change volume to 50" Margin="100"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```vb
Inherits Page

Private mElement As MediaElement
Private Synth As SpeechSynthesizer
Private currentStream As SpeechSynthesisStream 

Private Async Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    mElement = New MediaElement
    rootgrid.Children.Add(mElement)
End Sub

Async Function SayAsync(ByVal text As String) As Task
    Synth = New SpeechSynthesizer
    currentStream = Await Synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text)
    mElement.Volume = 10 / 100
    mElement.PlaybackRate = 50 / 100
    mElement.SetSource(currentStream, String.Empty)

End Function

Private Async Sub btnstart_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Await SayAsync("The privacy statement was declined." +
       "Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Speech, inking and typing, and ensure you" +
       "have viewed the privacy policy, and 'Get To Know You' is enabled.")
End Sub

Private Sub btnchangevolume_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    mElement.Volume = 50 / 100
End Sub
```

The possible reason may be that you didn't add the `MediaElement` to XAML after it was created code behind. If you still have issues please provide a minimal reproduced project.

By the way, in Windows 10, build 1607 or later and on we recommend that you use [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement) in place of `MediaElement`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. 
The reason it didn’t work was that I hadn’t added the MediaElement to the XAML as you said.
Now that it works I have upgraded my code to use the MediaPlayerElement instead of the MediaElement